# What is the meaning of SETAFFINITY ret = -1 in Android Studio? Here is the log of my Activity

Tags: android, android-studio

In the below code, I've set the new Intent  in the autocomplete_next TextView, but in my Mobile, when I run the app, and When I try to move to the next activity, It does not go the next Activity, Instead of that, it comes back again to the same previous Activity. In the Android Studio LOGCAT, I've seen the  `RenderScript: SETAFFINITY ret = -1`  . I got no trace about this error on Google?  Please Help me to fix my issue. Thank You in Advance...

> activity_calculator.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".CalculatorActivity"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

   <TableLayout
       android:id="@+id/tableinput"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">
       <TableRow
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_margin="5dp">
           <TextView
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:text="Operand 1 : "
               android:textSize="20dp"
               android:textAlignment="textStart"
               />

           <EditText
               android:id="@+id/oper1_edit_text"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:textSize="20dp"
               android:layout_weight="1"/>
       </TableRow>

       <TableRow
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_margin="5dp">
           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/autocomplete_textView"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:text="Operand 2 : "
               android:textSize="20dp"
               android:textAlignment="textStart"
               android:layout_weight="0"/>
           <EditText
               android:id="@+id/oper2_edit_text"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:textSize="20dp"
               android:layout_weight="1"/>
       </TableRow>
   </TableLayout>

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/calculator"
        android:layout_below="@id/tableinput"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add_btn"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:text="Add"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sub_btn"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:text="Sub"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/min_btn"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:text="Min"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/mul_btn"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:text="Multiply"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/div_btn"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:text="Divide"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/pow_btn"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:text="Power"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/max_btn"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:text="Max"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/rem_btn"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:text="Remainder"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/clear_btn"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:text="clear"/>

    </GridLayout>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_below="@id/calculator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/video_textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Ans: "
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ans_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </TableRow>
</RelativeLayout>
```

> CalculatorActivity.java (Activity which calls another Activity)

```
package com.example.lab_excercise_2;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.lang.Math;

public class CalculatorActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText oper1, oper2, ans;
private Button add_btn, sub_btn, div_btn, mul_btn, rem_btn, max_btn, min_btn, pow_btn, clear_btn;
private Integer oper1_text, oper2_text;
private TextView video_next,autocomplete_next;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculator);

    add_btn = findViewById(R.id.add_btn);
    sub_btn = findViewById(R.id.sub_btn);
    mul_btn = findViewById(R.id.mul_btn);
    div_btn = findViewById(R.id.div_btn);
    rem_btn = findViewById(R.id.rem_btn);
    min_btn = findViewById(R.id.min_btn);
    max_btn = findViewById(R.id.max_btn);
    pow_btn = findViewById(R.id.pow_btn);
    clear_btn = findViewById(R.id.clear_btn);
    oper1 = findViewById(R.id.oper1_edit_text);
    oper2 = findViewById(R.id.oper2_edit_text);
    ans = findViewById(R.id.ans_edit_text);

    video_next = findViewById(R.id.video_textView);
    autocomplete_next = findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_textView);

    add_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        oper1_text=Integer.parseInt(oper1.getText().toString());
        oper2_text=Integer.parseInt(oper2.getText().toString());
        ans.setText(String.valueOf(oper1_text+oper2_text));
    }
});
    sub_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        oper1_text=Integer.parseInt(oper1.getText().toString());
        oper2_text=Integer.parseInt(oper2.getText().toString());
        ans.setText(String.valueOf(oper1_text-oper2_text));
    }
});
    mul_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        oper1_text=Integer.parseInt(oper1.getText().toString());
        oper2_text=Integer.parseInt(oper2.getText().toString());
        ans.setText(String.valueOf(oper1_text*oper2_text));
    }
});
    div_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        oper1_text=Integer.parseInt(oper1.getText().toString());
        oper2_text=Integer.parseInt(oper2.getText().toString());
        ans.setText(String.valueOf(oper1_text/oper2_text));
    }
});
    rem_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        oper1_text=Integer.parseInt(oper1.getText().toString());
        oper2_text=Integer.parseInt(oper2.getText().toString());
        ans.setText(String.valueOf(oper1_text%oper2_text));
    }
});
    max_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        oper1_text=Integer.parseInt(oper1.getText().toString());
        oper2_text=Integer.parseInt(oper2.getText().toString());
        ans.setText((oper1_text>oper2_text ? oper1_text: oper2_text).toString());
    }
});

    min_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        oper1_text=Integer.parseInt(oper1.getText().toString());
        oper2_text=Integer.parseInt(oper2.getText().toString());
        ans.setText((oper1_text<oper2_text ? oper1_text: oper2_text).toString());
    }
});

    pow_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            oper1_text=Integer.parseInt(oper1.getText().toString());
            oper2_text=Integer.parseInt(oper2.getText().toString());
            Double pow = Math.pow(oper1_text,oper2_text);
            ans.setText(pow.toString());
        }
    });

    clear_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        oper1.setText("");
        oper2.setText("");
        ans.setText("");
    }

});

    video_next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent videoIntent = new Intent(CalculatorActivity.this,VideoActivity.class);
            startActivity(videoIntent);
        }
    });

    autocomplete_next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent autocompleteIntent = new Intent(CalculatorActivity.this,AutocompleteActivity.class);
            startActivity(autocompleteIntent);
        }
    });

}
}
```

> activity_autocomplete.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".AutocompleteActivity">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Date-Time Picker Autocomplete"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/setTime_btn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:text="Set Time"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/time_text"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"/>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/setDate_btn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:text="Set Date"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date_text"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"/>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/label_text"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Label  "
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <MultiAutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/label_edit"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="3" />



        </TableRow>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/setalarm_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:text="Set Time" />

    </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

> AutocompleteActivity.java (Activity which was called by the above Activity)

```
package com.example.lab_excercise_2;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.MultiAutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class AutocompleteActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button setTime, setDate, setalarm;
private TextView time_text, date_text, label_text;
private Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
private String date_string, time_string, label_string;
private String[] labels = {"Wake Up","Time to School","Time to College","Time to Work","Complete Activity","Finish Project"};
private MultiAutoCompleteTextView label_autocomplete;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_autocomplete);

    setTime = findViewById(R.id.setTime_btn);
    setDate = findViewById(R.id.setDate_btn);
    setalarm = findViewById(R.id.setalarm_btn);
    time_text = findViewById(R.id.time_text);
    date_text = findViewById(R.id.date_text);
    label_autocomplete = findViewById(R.id.label_edit);
    label_text = findViewById(R.id.label_textView);

    setDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDateDialog(setDate);
        }
    });

    setTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showTimeDialog(setTime);
        }
    });

    setalarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            nextpage(v);
        }
    });

    label_autocomplete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(AutocompleteActivity.this,AlarmActivity.class);
            startActivity(alarmIntent);
        }
    });

    label_text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(AutocompleteActivity.this,AlarmActivity.class);
            startActivity(alarmIntent);
        }
    });

    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,labels);
    label_autocomplete.setAdapter(adapter);
    label_autocomplete.setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());


}

public void showTimeDialog(final Button time){
    TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timeSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,hourOfDay);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,minute);
            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
            time_text.setText(simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));
        }
    };
    new TimePickerDialog(AutocompleteActivity.this,timeSetListener,calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE),false).show();
}

public void showDateDialog(final Button date){
    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR,year);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH,month);
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,dayOfMonth);
            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yy-MM-dd");
            date_text.setText(simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));
        }
    };
    new DatePickerDialog(AutocompleteActivity.this, dateSetListener,calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
}

public void nextpage(View view){
    date_string = date_text.getText().toString();
    time_string = time_text.getText().toString();
    label_string = label_autocomplete.getText().toString();
    Intent nextIntent = new Intent(this,Autocomplete2Activity.class);
    nextIntent.putExtra("date",date_string);
    nextIntent.putExtra("time",time_string);
    nextIntent.putExtra("label",label_string);
    startActivity(nextIntent);

}
}
```

> LOGCAT

```
2020-03-02 19:55:10.865 4078-4136/com.example.lab_excercise_2E/RenderScript: SETAFFINITY ret = -1
2020-03-02 19:55:10.865 4078-4137/com.example.lab_excercise_2 E/RenderScript: SETAFFINITY ret = -1
2020-03-02 19:55:10.865 4078-4139/com.example.lab_excercise_2 E/RenderScript: SETAFFINITY ret = -1
2020-03-02 19:55:10.865 4078-4138/com.example.lab_excercise_2 E/RenderScript: SETAFFINITY ret = -1
2020-03-02 19:55:10.865 4078-4140/com.example.lab_excercise_2 E/RenderScript: SETAFFINITY ret = -1
2020-03-02 19:55:10.865 4078-4142/com.example.lab_excercise_2 E/RenderScript: SETAFFINITY ret = -1
2020-03-02 19:55:10.865 4078-4141/com.example.lab_excercise_2 E/RenderScript: SETAFFINITY ret = -1`
```

Comment: Can you add full code of your activity?

Comment: That was my full code

Comment: Added both calling Activity and Called Activity with XML layouts

Comment: It seems there is a third activity called "AlarmActivity", but you didn't provide code for it. Also did you make a typo in this line 'label_text = findViewById(R.id.label_textView);'? Bkoz there is no such id like 'label_textView'

Comment: I run your code and the transition to the AutocompleteActivity from CalculatorActivity works fine.

Comment: Thnx for your help. The typo error was making the problem on my machine. When I correct it the code runs smoothly.

Comment: But I wonder what does that error means. SET AFFINITY ret = -1.